# Ursina - Setup screen size - windows.size is not working

Tags: python

How to setup the screen size in Ursina. I would like to create something in a 800x600 windows for example and window.size isnt working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

### Overview and Solution

I believe I have the solution. You need the `window.update_aspect_ratio()` function and the `window.late_init()` function. The final code looks like this...

---

```
from ursina import *

app = Ursina()

window.windowed_size = 0.3
window.update_aspect_ratio()
window.late_init()

app.run()
```

---

### How It Works

You want to change the size, so you need to update the ration between the angles. This is why you use the `window.update_aspect_ratio()` function. The `window.late_init()` function reinitializes the window to update how it looks.

---

### Size in Pixels

You cannot choose the size in terms of pixels, but it works with a proportion of the initial size. If you know the size of your full screen, you can use an equation by finding the relation ship between the intended size and the full screen size. You can change `window.windowed_size = 0.3` to...

```
window.windowed_size = window.fullscreen_size / 1.2 #(or whatever the ratio is you've calculated)
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is setting the size like this: `Ursina(size=(800,600))`

Answer (score 0):

```
from ursina import *
app = Ursina(borderless=False)

window.size = (800,600)
app.run()
```

Try this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).